# Powershell Scheduled Task Issue: New-ScheduledTaskAction : Invalid namespace

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the below mentioned script to schedule a powershell task on a virtual machine:

```
$tName = "RunMyScript1"
$tCommand = "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$tArgs = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\abc\Desktop\CommandConsoleAlert.ps1"
$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)
$tAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$tCommand" -Argument $tArgs
$uName = "$env:userdomain" + "\" + "$env:username"
$tTrigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepeatIndefinitely -RepetitionInterval $repeat
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $tAction -Trigger $tTrigger -TaskName "$tName" -User $uName
```

However, I am getting below error message-

New-ScheduledTaskAction : Invalid namespace
At N:\USERS\abc\CLS_Server_Scripts\PowerShellScheduledTask.ps1:5 char:12

- $tAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$tCommand" -Argument $tA ...
- ```
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [New-ScheduledTaskAction], CimException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,New-ScheduledTaskAction

Note: I am using powershell version 5

Could someone please help me with the issue.

Comment: There's no need to use quotes around $tCommand here: `$tAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$tCommand" -Argument $tArgs`

Comment: removing  double quotes from "$tCommand" still gives the same error.